# Auto resize card-content (materialize css) with an ag-Grid in it

Tags: html, css, angularjs, materialize, ag-grid

In a card-tabs element from `materialize css` framework I'm trying to setup an `ag-grid` table.

Here is the code.

```
        <div class="card-tabs">
          <ul class="tabs tabs-fixed-width">
            <li class="tab"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#test5">Test 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="card-content  grey lighten-5">

          <div id="test4" style="height: 200px;">

            <div ag-grid="$ctrl.gridOptions" class="ag-theme-material" style="height: 100%;"></div>

          </div>

          <div id="test5">Test 5 content</div>
        </div>

       </div>
```

The problem is that I cannot auto resize the height of the element with `id='test4'` in order to gird be viewable. If I remove the `style="height:200px;"` from it, the grid doesn't show up. If I added it's being shown but I don't want to keep it statically on `200px` since the grid's height could be varied.

Is there any way to make the div with the `id='test4'` automatically resize itself according to the size of the `ag-grid`?

I tried to put `height:auto;` both in `card-content` and `test4` divs but without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Div will not be shown if there is not content in it. Why don't you just put blank `&nbsp` value inside html.

```
    <div class="card-tabs">
      <ul class="tabs tabs-fixed-width">
        <li class="tab"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#test5">Test 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="card-content  grey lighten-5">

      <div id="test4"

        <div ag-grid="$ctrl.gridOptions" class="ag-theme-material" style="height: 100%;"></div>
       &nbsp;
      </div>

      <div id="test5">Test 5 content</div>
    </div>

   </div>
```

Comment: No. That's not the problem definitely. I have to define a specific height for the parent element in order the 100% of the ag-grid to be used.